# Trying to make loop for written function work, R

Tags: r, function, loops

I am trying to get a loop to work. It is a loop for a written function (written by someone else). When I use the function without a loop, it works. But when I try to write a loop, it throws an error.

Here is some sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(RegNum = c("pool", "101003", "104004", "104013", 
"105001", "pool", "104009", "101044", "102001", "104005", "pool", 
"104001", "101036", "101027", "104007", "pool", "105004", "104012", 
"102004", "104008", "pool", "101038", "105002", "101041", "104003", 
"pool", "104014", "105005", "pool"), Anhydro_1.5_D_glucitol = c(2597L, 
2525L, 1796L, 2606L, 2806L, 2556L, 3539L, 43L, 2682L, 1444L, 
2554L, 2932L, 4464L, 5119L, 4052L, 2345L, 2733L, 1475L, 3047L, 
446L, 2436L, 2218L, 2306L, 2310L, 1872L, 2747L, 2415L, 1868L, 
2432L), Levoglucosan = c(3756L, 2524L, 1136L, 1753L, 1445L, 3121L, 
1306L, 10071L, 873L, 23161L, 2804L, 1396L, 1526L, 1095L, 2093L, 
2539L, 3155L, 849L, 1418L, 1160L, 3251L, 927L, 1946L, 967L, 1004L, 
2461L, 744L, 708L, 2535L), Hexadecanol_1 = c(472L, 643L, 572L, 
666L, 717L, 895L, 868L, 643L, 1096L, 720L, 770L, 900L, 904L, 
1237L, 839L, 516L, 583L, 776L, 601L, 779L, 817L, 801L, 722L, 
675L, 681L, 678L, 758L, 712L, 916L), SorbitolISTD_13C6 = c(3141L, 
2024L, 2550L, 2759L, 2914L, 3012L, 2802L, 3247L, 2597L, 2942L, 
2970L, 2987L, 3024L, 4075L, 4321L, 3051L, 2540L, 2907L, 2977L, 
2625L, 2972L, 2169L, 2736L, 3257L, 2748L, 3105L, 2680L, 2087L, 
2975L), Aminobutyricacid_2 = c(683L, 374L, 1330L, 406L, 426L, 
544L, 520L, 1241L, 829L, 632L, 963L, 1269L, 553L, 2140L, 3005L, 
988L, 611L, 926L, 768L, 629L, 632L, 421L, 1015L, 656L, 876L, 
994L, 1088L, 1118L, 651L), Ethanolamine = c(7900L, 4546L, 6028L, 
3556L, 3344L, 4066L, 1940L, 11296L, 3697L, 10477L, 6516L, 3078L, 
5824L, 15197L, 10434L, 5937L, 5423L, 8528L, 5974L, 3478L, 4574L, 
3106L, 22693L, 4066L, 14693L, 5695L, 9506L, 7210L, 3997L)), row.names = 2:30, class = 
"data.frame")
```

It is a function to calculate the Intraclass Correlation Coefficient (ICC). When I run the function without a loop, it works:

```
icc9(y="Anhydro_1.5_D_glucitol", subject = "RegNum", dat=df)
```

the y= argument specifies which column to estimate an ICC for. The subject argument is to specify the ID. And the dat argument specifies the dataframe to use.

I create an object to loop through:

```
## Find first metabolite column
metab.start <- which(colnames(df) == "Anhydro_1.5_D_glucitol"); metab.start 
## Find last metabolite column
metab.stop <- which(colnames(df) == "Ethanolamine"); metab.stop
metabolite.names <- colnames(df)[metab.start:metab.stop]
```

I try to run this code, but it does not work:

```
lapply(metabolite.names, function(response) {
 icc9(as.formula(paste0("y=",response)),subject="RegNum",dat=df)
 }) %>% do.call("rbind",.)
```

This is the error and warning I get:

```
Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : cannot set attribute on a symbol
In addition: Warning message:
invalid formula "y=Anhydro_1.5_D_glucitol": assignment is deprecated
```

This syntax produces an error too:

```
lapply(metabolite.names, function(response) {  
icc9(y=response,subject="RegNum",dat=df)  }) %>% do.call("rbind",.)
```

The error says:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular') Error in 
asMethod(object) : not a positive definite matrix In addition: 
Warning message: In sqrt(m) : NaNs produced
```

I think it may be an issue of not pulling the names in correctly. When I run the syntax below, it produces the same boundary error as above. So that was why I was trying different methods to pull the names in. The names need to be in quotes it seems. That when the individual function works and does not produce an error

```
icc9(y=df$beta_Alanine,subject = "RegNum", dat=df)
```

If you need it, here is the code that was used to create the function:

```
icc9 <- function(y,subject,fixed=NULL,dat,method="ML"){

# Quick install from github
p <-   rownames(installed.packages())
if ("devtools" %in% p == "FALSE") install.packages("devtools")
if ("bootmlm" %in% p == "FALSE") devtools::install_github("marklhc/bootmlm")

data <- dat

# quick function to format my estimates/confidence intervals
formatEstimate <- function(est, lcl, ucl){
a <- format(round(est,2),nsmall=2)
b <- format(round(lcl,2),nsmall=2)
c <- format(round(ucl,2),nsmall=2)
return(paste0(a, " (",b,",",c,")"))
}

# drop any missings from the dataset
dat <- dat[!is.na(dat[[subject]]),]
dat <- dat[!is.na(dat[[y]]),]

# Define my input variables
SUBJECT <- data[[subject]]
Y <- data[[y]]
if (is.null(fixed)) {FIXED <- NULL} else {FIXED <- as.matrix(data[,fixed])}

# Frequency stuff first
tabx.f <- data.frame(table(SUBJECT))
tabx.p <- data.frame(prop.table(table(SUBJECT)))
tabx <- data.frame(subjid=tabx.f$SUBJECT, COUNT=tabx.f$Freq, PERCENT=tabx.p$Freq*100,
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
rm(tabx.f,tabx.p)


# tab3 lists the number of unique subjects, number of observations, and average obs per 
subject
tab3 <- data.frame(numw2=nrow(tabx),
                 obsw2=sum(tabx$COUNT,na.rm=T))
tab3$avgrep <- tab3$obsw2/tab3$numw2
rm(tabx)

# Step 1 - run the model
# Subject ID is always a random effects
# Y is the response
# FIXED is optional
# Method - inputs are "ML" or "REML", default is "ML"

# Sets modelmethod to logical
# the lmer() function has an option "REML=T/F"
# This little bit of code will just fill in that option
if (method == "ML") modelmethod <- F
if (method != "ML") modelmethod <- T

if (!is.null(FIXED)) {
f <- formula(paste0("Y ~ ",paste(c("(1|SUBJECT)","FIXED"),collapse="+")))
} else {
f <- formula("Y ~ (1|SUBJECT)")
}
fit <- lme4::lmer(f, REML=modelmethod)  # model object
z <- summary(fit)       # summary object

# Extract the asymptotic covariance matrix
asycov <- data.frame(bootmlm::vcov_vc(fit,F))
names(asycov) <- c("CovP1","CovP2")  # Renaming to match the SAS program
row.names(asycov) <- c("Intercept","Residual")

# Pull out the covariance parameters
estimates <- data.frame(z$varcor)
estimates <- estimates[,c("grp","vcov","sdcor")]
names(estimates) <- c("Parm","Estimate","SD")

# Pull out the fixed effects estimates
fixed_effects <- data.frame(z$coefficients)[1,]
names(fixed_effects) <- c("Estimate","SE","T")

# Everything I need is in the asycov, random-estimates and fixed-estimates matrices
subject_estimate <- estimates$Estimate[estimates$Parm=="SUBJECT"]
residual_estimate <- estimates$Estimate[estimates$Parm=="Residual"]
residual_covp2 <- asycov["Residual","CovP2"]
intercept_covp1 <- asycov["Intercept","CovP1"]
intercept_covp2 <- asycov["Intercept","CovP2"]
fixed_estimate <- fixed_effects$Estimate
variance_fixed <- fixed_effects$SE^2


# ICC and confidence intervals
ICC_Variance <- (subject_estimate^2 * residual_covp2+residual_estimate^2 * 
intercept_covp1-2*subject_estimate*residual_estimate*intercept_covp2)
/subject_estimate^4
ICC <- estimates$Estimate[estimates$Parm=="SUBJECT"] / sum(estimates$Estimate)
logICC <- log(ICC / (1-ICC))
SE_ICC <- sqrt(((ICC^2) * ICC_Variance) / ((1-ICC)^2))
logLL <- logICC - 1.96*SE_ICC
logUL <- logICC + 1.96*SE_ICC
ICCLL <- exp(logLL) / (1+exp(logLL))
ICCUL <- exp(logUL) / (1+exp(logUL))
finalICC <- formatEstimate(ICC, ICCLL, ICCUL)
rm(ICC_Variance,logICC,ICC,SE_ICC,logLL,logUL,ICCLL,ICCUL)



# Overall CV
Variance_CV <- residual_covp2 / (4*fixed_estimate^2 * residual_estimate) +
(residual_estimate / fixed_estimate^4) * variance_fixed

CV <- sqrt(residual_estimate) / z$coefficients["(Intercept)","Estimate"]
logCV <- log(CV)
varCV <- (1/CV^2) * Variance_CV
logLL <- logCV - 1.96*sqrt(varCV)
logUL <- logCV + 1.96*sqrt(varCV)
CVLL <- exp(logLL)
CVUL <- exp(logUL)
finalCV <- formatEstimate(CV, CVLL, CVUL)

# Create a final data frame with:
# n-unique subject
# n-observations
# avg-N per subject
final <- data.frame(Response=y,tab3,ICC=finalICC,CV=finalCV,stringsAsFactors=F)
names(final) <- 
c("Response_Variable","N_subjects","N_Observations","Average_Measurements","ICC","CV")
return(final)
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `as.formula` and `paste`?! This does not correspond at all to your loop-less code; in fact, it does something completely different. Just use the same code, i.e. `icc9(y = response, …)`. — The other error you’re getting should also exist if you run the `icc9` function individually on the corresponding column, it’s unrelated to the loop code.

Comment: I double-checked to ensure that I was not getting the error with running the function individually versus the loop. I do not get the error with that syntax to run it for 1 variable at a time. But I get it with the loop. So there is something about how I am writing my loop that is not working.

Comment: I will say, I get the same error when I use this syntax individually: icc9(y=df$beta_Alanine,subject = "RegNum", dat=df). So it could be an issue of how I am specifying the names of the variables in the loop. I have tried several things to pull the names in correctly. But it does not appear to work

Comment: So you're saying that `icc9(y="Anhydro_1.5_D_glucitol", subject = "RegNum", dat=df)` works but `icc9(y="beta_Alanine", subject = "RegNum", dat=df)` throws an error? Then there is a problem with the data such that the model for the latter cannot be fit. Using `lapply(metabolite.names, function(response) {  icc9(y=response, subject="RegNum",dat=df)  }) %>% do.call("rbind",.)` is the correct syntax for the function. You should be passing in values by character name.